# Is there a way to get beautified log entry using Monolog?

Tags: php, logging, monolog

Now my code looks like this:

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$ipAddress = GeoIp\Manager::getRealIp();
$geoResult = GeoIp\Manager::getDataResult($ipAddress, 'ru');

$logger = new Logger('Debug');
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/logs/geo.log', Logger::DEBUG));
$logger->info('Location:', array('object' => print_r($geoResult, true)));
```

As a result I have one-line log entry. I tried to use `JsonFormatter`, but is just formats the data structure and continues print one-line records, when I want a few-line **human readable** beautified presentation of data.

**UPDATE:**

I found solution here later. [Symfony2 - How to log multiline entries with monolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312746/symfony2-how-to-log-multiline-entries-with-monolog?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) And for me it looks like this:

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

$ipAddress = GeoIp\Manager::getRealIp();
$geoResult = GeoIp\Manager::getDataResult($ipAddress, 'ru');

$formatter = new LineFormatter(null, null, true);

$stream = new StreamHandler($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/logs/geo.log', Logger::DEBUG);
$stream->setFormatter($formatter);

$logger = new Logger('Debug');
$logger->pushHandler($stream);
$logger->info('Location:', array('object' => print_r($geoResult, true)));
```

Comment: this looks promising. https://github.com/skyzyx/monolog-json-pretty-print-formatter

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT flat as following:-

```
$beautifiedJsonObjectString = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
// now you can use the formatted objected as you like
```

Reference: https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2008/03/11/format-json-with-php/

Comment: It have not worked. But I found the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312746/symfony2-how-to-log-multiline-entries-with-monolog?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Since version `2.0.0` the `Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter`, or any formatter that extends `Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter`, supports this via `setJsonPrettyPrint()`

```
$formatter = new JsonFormatter();
$formatter->setJsonPrettyPrint(true);
```

There is also a more generic JSON encoding option if needed

```
$formatter->addJsonEncodeOption($option);
```